# Find li by ::marker value

Tags: javascript, html-lists, pseudo-element

I'm writing javascript to resolve references to a series of nested lists with varying `list-style-type` values set, containing both `ul` and `ol` elements. The references are of the format XX.XX.XX where each subsequent XX refers to another level down of the list.

For example, here is what IV.b.i would resolve to:

```css
.l-upper-roman {
  list-style-type: upper-roman;
}

.l-lower-roman {
  list-style-type: lower-roman;
}

.l-lower-alpha {
  list-style-type: lower-alpha;
}
```

```html
<ol id="outer-list" class="l-upper-roman">
  <li>not this</li>
  <li>not this either</li>
  <li>nope</li>
  <li>
    <ol class="l-lower-alpha">
      <li>this is not it</li>
      <li>
        <ol class="l-lower-roman">
          <li>This is the correct element!</li>
          <li>not me</li>
        </ol>
      </li>
      <li>wrong</li>
      <li>not it</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>wrong</li>
</ol>
```

In that list, a reference like 4.2.1 would be invalid, because the list contains IV, not 4.

Traversing a list of elements is easy, but the trouble comes in trying to find the exact value of the `::marker` of a given `li` to check if it matches.

So, my question is, how can I find the value of the `::marker` for a given `li` element?